# Turn an hourly temperature table into a single time series in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame with the following customer data from a 24 hour shopping location:

```
Date      #Cust at 00:00 Items/Cust at 00:00  Ttl Items at 00:00 #Cust at 01:00 Items/Cust at 01:00  Ttl Items at 01:00 ....#Cust at 23:00 Items/Cust at 23:00  Ttl Items at 23:00
1/1/2018       2            4                         8                1           5                         5                    3            3                       9
1/2/2018       2            5                        10                1           5                         5                    3            4                      12
....
```

I want to turn it into a straightforward time series data frame:

```
Time Stamp         #Cust  Items/Cust Ttl Cust
00:00 1/1/2018      2         4         8
01:00 1/1/2018      1         5         5 
.....
23:00 1/1/2018      3         3         9
00:00 1/1/2018      2         5        10
01:00 1/1/2018      1         5         5 
.....
23:00 1/1/2018      3         4        12
```

etc....

I know that it should involve pd.melt, but given that I have multiple value columns, I can't figure out the syntax.

Comment: For loop over rows and another over columns, and construct your dataseries inside as dict of lists. Maybe not the most elegant or efficient way to do it but simple enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can create index by columns without `at` first by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), then use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by columns for `MultiIndex`, so possible use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html). Last data cleaning - [`DataFrame.swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html), [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html)
 and [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.set_index('Date')
df.columns = df.columns.str.split(' at ', expand=True)
df1 = df.stack().swaplevel(1,0).rename_axis(('Time','Stamp')).reset_index()
print (df1)
    Time     Stamp  #Cust  Items/Cust  Ttl Items
0  00:00  1/1/2018      2           4          8
1  01:00  1/1/2018      1           5          5
2  23:00  1/1/2018      3           3          9
3  00:00  1/2/2018      2           5         10
4  01:00  1/2/2018      1           5          5
5  23:00  1/2/2018      3           4         12
```

If need datetimes:

```
df = df.set_index('Date')
df.columns = df.columns.str.split(' at ',expand=True)
df1 = df.stack().swaplevel(1,0).rename_axis(('TimeStamp','Date')).reset_index()
df1['TimeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.pop('Date') + ' ' + df1['TimeStamp'])
print (df1)
            TimeStamp  #Cust  Items/Cust  Ttl Items
0 2018-01-01 00:00:00      2           4          8
1 2018-01-01 01:00:00      1           5          5
2 2018-01-01 23:00:00      3           3          9
3 2018-01-02 00:00:00      2           5         10
4 2018-01-02 01:00:00      1           5          5
5 2018-01-02 23:00:00      3           4         12
```

Also for `DatetimeIndex`:

```
df = df.set_index('Date')
df.columns = df.columns.str.split(' at ',expand=True)
df1 = df.stack()
idx = pd.to_datetime(df1.index.get_level_values(0) + ' ' + df1.index.get_level_values(1))
df1 = df1.set_index(idx).rename_axis('Timestamp')
print (df1)
                     #Cust  Items/Cust  Ttl Items
Timestamp                                        
2018-01-01 00:00:00      2           4          8
2018-01-01 01:00:00      1           5          5
2018-01-01 23:00:00      3           3          9
2018-01-02 00:00:00      2           5         10
2018-01-02 01:00:00      1           5          5
2018-01-02 23:00:00      3           4         12
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use [`pandas.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html)

```
import pandas as pd

new_df = pd.wide_to_long(df, ['#Cust', 'Ttl Items', 'Items/Cust'], 
                         i='Date', 
                         j='time', 
                         sep = ' at ', suffix='.+').reset_index()

new_df.index = pd.to_datetime(new_df['Date'] + ' ' + new_df['time'], dayfirst=True)
new_df.drop(['Date', 'time'], 1, inplace=True)
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
                     #Cus  Ttl Items  Items/Cus
2018-01-01 00:00:00     2          8          4
2018-02-01 00:00:00     2         10          5
2018-01-01 01:00:00     1          5          5
2018-02-01 01:00:00     1          5          5
2018-01-01 23:00:00     3          9          3
2018-02-01 23:00:00     3         12          4
```